# ajaxFileUpload duplicated request in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome

I was use ajaxFileUpload to upload multiple file through ajax.
Here's my code

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url:url_site('Backend/Global/upload/index'+query),
    secureuri:false,
    fileElementId:'file',
    data:{
        name:'logan', 
        id:'id'
    },
    success: function (data, status){
        $('#result-file').append(data.msg);
    }
})
```

Everything worked OK in Chrome 35- and orther browser
When I update Chrome 36, it has an issue. It send many duplicated requests and upload many duplicated files. When I remove

```
fileElementId:'file',
```

It stopped but file cannot be uploaded. I think the problem here is the Chrome browser. Please, help me fix this!
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a serious bug in Google Chrome 36 http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388795.
Only wait for new release.

Comment: Solved: I created a button and use onclick() after choose file upload instead of onchange(). Thanks you anyway!